# Vim: match N'th occurance of PATTERN and highlight only that pattern on the matching line

Tags: vim

With the regular expression below one can match the N'th occurance of PATTERN, however when one runs it the highlighting continues for each next N'th match on the line.
How to limit the highlighting only to the N'th pattern on each matching line?

```
/\(.\{-}\zs\(PATTERN\)\)\{N}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight only the N'th pattern in a line, just anchor to the beginning of the line (with `^`):

```
/^\(.\{-}\zs\(PATTERN\)\)\{N}
```

With `\%#` you can highlight the N'th pattern *after the cursor* instead (note that you need to toggle `'hlsearch'` or `:redraw` to see updated search highlighting):

```
/\%#\(.\{-}\zs\(PATTERN\)\)\{N}
```